# Is it possible to reach 50k in the game 2048 with only having a highest tile of 512?

Tags: recreational-mathematics

Is it possible to reach a score of 50,000 in the game 2048 with only having a highest tile of 512(Only one 512 was present) and one 256 tile and other small numbered tiles such as 2,4,8,16,...,64.

Because my friend has done so in her phone and I am quite skeptical about it so I decided to ask.

Please do show a mathematical explanation instead of giving a direct answer

Comment: Some explanation might help.  I have no idea what you're talking about in this question.

Comment: @RobertIsrael I assume the OP is asking about [this game](http://sujeetgholap.github.io/2048/).

Comment: See this video explaining the scores: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OO4tA5i7X9g&feature=youtu.be

Comment: In theory, yes, anything is possible. I feel safe saying this because this morning I found Waldo inside an Easter egg.

Comment: Yea, everything is possible... until proven impossible.

Comment: I got that score while i had one of 4096 so I would assume in the best scenario at least an 1024 would have to be present or even a 2048

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you get $n$ points for forming an $2^n$-tile (ie. $32$ points for forming a tile with $32$ on it, etc). But that doesn't mean that if you *have* a $2^n$-tile, you'll have a score of $2^n$. That's forgetting the amount of points you got from all the intermediate tiles you would have had to form to get that tile.

If you have a $2^n$ tile, you get $2^n$ score from that tile. But that tile was formed from two $2^{n-1}$ tiles, which would have been formed from four $2^{n-2}$ tiles, and so on. So if you see a $2^n$ tiles on the board, the total score from it and everything that went into making it is at most:

$$2^n+2\cdot2^{n-1}+2^22^{n-2}+...=\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}2^{n-k}2^k=(n-1)2^n$$

I'm summing up to $n-2$ because I'm assuming the best-case scenario where all the basic tiles (given to you by the game) were $2$s, which will maximize your score.

So the score for a $512=2^9$ is at most $8\cdot512=4096$. In the best case scenario where you end with one $512$, one $256$, and the other $14$ tiles $128$s, your score would be $16640$. So $50$ thousand certainly seems unlikely, unless there's some aspect of the scoring that I didn't take into account.

Comment: A couple typos:  In your first line, you should say you get $2^n$ points for forming a $2^n$ tile.  The second $n-1$ exponent should be $n-2$.  Then there might be multiple $512$'s and unfortunately a board of $512$'s except with $256$'s on a main diagonal scores $12*4096+4*7*256=56320$.  We need a (slightly) finer analysis to show you can't get more than $10\ \ 512$'s without having a chance to make a $1024$.  You are very close.

Comment: @RossMillikan I was simply taking into account the OP's information, which said the board contained one $512$, one $256$, and "other smaller tiles". The highest possible score with only $512$s would be an interesting, but distinct problem.

Comment: Good point.  I was just thinking of the highest allowable with nothing higher than $512$

Answer (score 0):

No, not possible I think. Lets count how many points we get by getting to a certain power of $2$. By my rough estimates, if you just have a bunch of $2's$, your score will be around $256$ when you get to $64$. From there, you get $512$ for two $64's$ and $512+128 < 650$ for a $128$. Then you get $650*2+256 < 1600$ for a $256$ and less than $3200+500 = 3700$ for a $512$. Then if your whole board was just filled with $512's$, your score would be less than $3700*16 = 59, 200$. Now, this is disregarding the difficulty of arranging everything...